# JAX-WS Web Service and environment entitys

Tags: eclipse, web-services, jax-ws

Fist off all I'm quit new to this stuff, so sorry if I don't describe my problem properly.
I've built a simple Jax-WS Web Service for Tomcat 6 by using the Eclipse Juno wizard (dynamic web project --> add class --> new Web Service --> create WAR) and AXIS 2.
Everything works fine, but now i want to store some environment entities in the web.xml file and make them accessible from the service.

If I were using a servlet, I would call ServletConfigurator.getinitparam("name"), but how do i do it with a web service?

Answer (score 0):

you might want to take a look at [this](http://www.9lessons.info/2012/09/restful-web-services-api-using-java-and.html) website for RESTful Web Services API using Java and MySQL.It's pretty informative.